# Could colons be optional when at end of line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I would like to understand whether it would be technically possible to change the syntax of Python making the colons of compound statements optional when they are at the end of the line, apart from whitespace and comments. For example:

```python
if so()
    print("yes")
else
    print("no")
```

- Would this change break existing Python code?
- Would there be ambiguous constructs?
- Would the parser become exceedingly bad at diagnosing some kind of error?
- Would there be another technical problem I can't think of now?

Of course, I know the argument that colons makes the code easier to read. I think this is debatable, but I absolutely don't want to discuss opinions here. My question is about possible technical problems. Please note that my question is not about the purpose of the colon.

According to the [syntax of compound statements in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html) there is always a `":"` before a `suite`, where `suite` is defined as

```
suite ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | NEWLINE INDENT statement+ DEDENT
```

Taking as an example the `if` statement

```
if_stmt ::=  "if" expression ":" suite
             ("elif" expression ":" suite)*
             ["else" ":" suite]
```

the syntax could, apparently, be modified like this:

```
suite ::=  ":" stmt_list NEWLINE | [":"] NEWLINE INDENT statement+ DEDENT

if_stmt ::=  "if" expression suite
             ("elif" expression suite)*
             ["else" suite]
```

In the [Grammar file of the CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Grammar/Grammar#L114) (also available [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html)) things are a bit different, and a bit complicated by the optional [type comment](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-comments) after the colon in some constructs, but all in all it seems to me that it should be possible to modify the syntax similarly to the above.

What technical impediments would there be?

---

The following could be a more [LL(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser)-friendly syntax for `suite`:

```
suite ::=  colon_suite | indented_suite
colon_suite ::=  ":" (stmt_list NEWLINE | indented_suite)
indented_suite ::=  NEWLINE INDENT statement+ DEDENT
```

Comment: One thing that immediately comes to mind, trivial one-liners: `if so(): print("yes")` parser could possible try to make sense out of it, but it would have to look into semantics and not just try to understand condition left of `:`. And yeah, sorry for an opinion, but it'd be really hard to read in that case. :)

Comment: @OndrejK. please read the question again. In the first paragraph I have highlighted the part you missed.

Comment: I suspect that moving the `:` into the definition of suite might have implications for the grammar's status as an LL grammar.

Comment: @chepner, I don't think so, because I don't think that the newline after a “clause” can be ambiguous. But I would be glad to be shown that there would actually be a problem with the grammar.

Comment: Informally, I think the problem with your proposed definition of `suite` is that seeing a `:` as the next token is not enough to choose between the `stmt_list` rule and the `statement+` rule; at least one more token is needed, to see if it is a `NEWLINE` or one of the tokens that can ultimately begin a `small_stmt`.

Comment: So you could define a grammar that would let the `:` be optional, but it would no longer be be parsable with an LL(1) parser.

Comment: I didn't write the definition with an LL(1) grammar in mind, it would need to be rearranged, just like the content of the Grammar file is rearranged with respect to the grammar in the docs

Comment: IMO this question has been closed by mistake. This question is about the technical feasibility of making the colon optional when at end of line. The question this one has been marked as being a duplicate of is about the _purpose_ of the colon, a completely _different_ question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookahead technicalities aside, the grammar would certainly not become ambiguous: all you’re doing is interpolating a `:` at the end of any line (before any comment) where doing so avoids a syntax error (so not after `lambda`, where one would be necessary but not sufficient).  In particular, no suite introduction can be extended over multiple lines except with backslashes or inside bracketing characters (one can’t write `for` and `in`, or `except` and `as`, on separate logical lines, for instance).

The only obvious candidates for an impaired diagnostic would be confusion with a ternary conditional or generator expression, but that’s very weak because of the expression before the `if`/`for` (and the parenthesis for the latter).  There would probably be no technical impediments at all.

Comment: when you say “suite introduction”, do you mean the “header” of a “clause” (see the [3rd paragraph here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html))? (BTW, I realize now that I got a comment to my question wrong, I used “clause” instead of “header” thereof)

Comment: also, the part with the `lambda` is not so clear to me

Comment: @WalterTross: Yes, the header.  Adding a colon to `if lambda` doesn’t fix the problem like adding one to `if True` does.

Answer (score -2):

Since python conditional statements are delimited by indents, the : would serve as a redundant token when the execution block is expressed in a new line with a deeper indent.

I am not sure as someone said if this works on same line statements where you need a token to separate the condition from execution statements

Comment: regarding your first sentence: it doesn't point out any problem. Regarding the second: please read my question again, especially the highlighted part in the first paragraph

Comment: why would anyone change and write two sets of compiler code, one for single line conditionals and one for multi line conditionals. I hope using : is widely used and please not to try change it